# Cannot get srcset to work cross device

Tags: html, responsive-design, srcset

I've got a main header image:

```
<img class="hero" src="/assets/images/Food-Spread-500x167.jpg" alt="banner image" sizes="(min-width: 992px) 80vw, 100vw"
srcset="/assets/images/Food-Spread-500x167.jpg 500w,
        /assets/images/Food-Spread-768x256.jpg 768w,
        /assets/images/Food-Spread-992x331.jpg 992w,
        /assets/images/Food-Spread-1200x400.jpg 1200w">
```

The difficulty I'm having is twofold:

1. Which size should you set as the src fallback? Largest or smallest? IE doesn't support srcset at all, so you'd be left with a tiny image as your header!! Safari (mac) struggles with it too...
2. Because there no way to say 'n'vw 2x  how do you get this to work on iphone? (As it's
   retina it obviously thinks it's twice as big as it is and pulls a
   much larger image than required). Is there something that can be done about this??

   Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't understand your problem in (2). You want the iPhone to download a "2x" image, right?

Comment: Hi @zcorpan, If the image is coded as it is above then the iphone, having twice the pixel density comes out as ~600px (rather than ~300) and hence chooses the second src. This means that that image, is twice as big as it needs to be and hence goes outside the viewport... 

Thinking about it, is it supposed to take a bigger image? Do you lock it to size with css??

Comment: It is supposed to pick a bigger image, but it is then supposed to scale it down again. Which iOS version? Are you using picturefill? Which version?

Comment: Not using picturefill. IOS version is: 8.1.3 (12b466)

Comment: Umm, Iphone is 640px...

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Yes, (because it's retina) but it's not being crunched down at all. The image is twice as wide as the viewport and it causes overflow problems...

Comment: The actual pixel width of the screen is 640px the browser renders a webpage at 320px, so why not set the imgae to 320px

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith You mean with css? So .hero {width: 100%}?? That's what I've done at the moment. It just seems weird that you have to do that with css when you have this interface...

Comment: The `srcset` attribute is just picking out what image will fit best, it does not size it for you. Since your screen is 640px it will grab the closet image to the 640px, it is your job through the css to make it smaller to fit the browser 320px.

Comment: @user1775718 Also looks like the "w" descriptor is not supported by your IOS anyways http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset

Comment: @zcorpan Picturefill seems to have fixed most of my problems, so if you want to add an answer I can mark that as accepted.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I presumed that if the browser thinks the page is 320 but knows it's viewport is 640 that it would correct for that. Regardless of my misunderstanding, thanks for your help. I've upvoted your comments...  :)

Comment: @user1775718 actually this topic is very very confusing, i don't think there are many people that fully understand the `srcset` attribute. I know enough to get myself in trouble and it freakin confuses the hell outta me.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No, it *should* downscale the image, per spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can pick any one you like! You have to make a tradeoff between what is most appropriate for legacy desktop browsers and what is most appropriate for legacy mobile browsers.
2. Your issue here is that Safari supports `srcset` with `x` descriptors, but not `w` or `sizes`. What happens is that the `sizes` attribute is ignored and it then either selects the first candidate in `srcset` as a "1x" or it ignores all candidates in `srcset` (depending on the version of Safari) and uses `src` instead. So you probably get the 500x167 image rendered as 500 CSS px wide, which overflows the (320 CSS px wide) viewport.

   You can do two things to fix this (you can do both if you like):

   - Use picturefill, it will add support for `w` and `sizes` and do the intrinsic sizing.
   - Set the width with CSS: `.hero { width:100% } 
     @media (min-width: 992px) { .hero { width:80% } }`

Comment: Also, since some early `srcset` implementations choose the first candidate in `srcset` when they don't understand the descriptors, I would recommend to put the candidate that you use in `src` first in `srcset`, at least if you opt to not use picturefill, so that they get the "right" fallback image.